# Debugging Realm, call stack does not have any app code

Tags: swift, realm, stack-trace

I've ran into this a few times, where the app will crash because of something Realm is trying to do, however the call stack is not helpful at all.  It get's me close (`TouchesEnded`), but i would think it should be a bit more accurate.  Is there a way to get closer?  In the past, i was able to figure it out because the crash message was pretty obvious, but this one could be happening anywhere.  Ideas?

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason:
>   'Expected object of type string for property 'id' on object of type
>   'DrawingNode', but received: 1'
>
> ```
> *** First throw call stack: (
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010713a1ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001067cff41 objc_exception_throw + 48
> 2   Realm                               0x0000000105190d31 _ZL15RLMPreconditionbP8NSStringS0_z + 657
> 3   Realm                               0x00000001052791b3 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_123validate_property_valueERKNS_15ColumnReferenceEP11objc_objectP8NSStringP15RLMObjectSchemaS6_ + 1011
> 4   Realm                               0x0000000105195ee7 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_112QueryBuilder22apply_value_expressionEP15RLMObjectSchemaP8NSStringP11objc_objectP21NSComparisonPredicate + 631
> 5   Realm                               0x00000001051928a3 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_112QueryBuilder15apply_predicateEP11NSPredicateP15RLMObjectSchema + 5075
> 6   Realm                               0x0000000105190eeb _Z19RLMPredicateToQueryP11NSPredicateP15RLMObjectSchemaP9RLMSchemaRN5realm5GroupE + 347
> 7   Realm                               0x0000000105152164 -[RLMManagedArray objectsWithPredicate:] + 324
> 8   RealmSwift                          0x0000000105c23d17 _T010RealmSwift4ListC6filterAA7ResultsCyxGSS_SayypGdtF + 231
> 9   DrawingApp                          0x0000000103fdb59a _T010DrawingApp0A5SceneC12touchesEndedys3SetVySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCSg4withtF + 26586
> 10  DrawingApp                          0x0000000103fdda88 _T010DrawingApp0A5SceneC12touchesEndedys3SetVySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCSg4withtFTo + 104
> 11  SpriteKit                           0x000000010a2eabbe -[SKView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 1083
> 12  UIKit                               0x0000000107a7ebbb -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2807
> 13  UIKit                               0x0000000107a802de -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
> 14  UIKit                               0x0000000107a23e36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
> 15  UIKit                               0x0000000108366434 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
> 16  UIKit                               0x0000000108369089 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
> 17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070dd231 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
> 18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010717ce41 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
> 19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070c1b49 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
> 20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070c112f __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
> 21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070c09b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
> 22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f46a9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
> 23  UIKit                               0x0000000107a075e8 UIApplicationMain + 159
> 24  DrawingApp                          0x0000000104071e17 main + 55
> 25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b0e4d81 start + 1
> )
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> ```

Comment: The call stack has several frames of code from your app, including making the call into Realm that results in the exception being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The backtrace shows that the exception is raised when your `DrawingScene.touchesEnded(_:with:)` method is calling `List.filter(_:)`. The exception messages indicates that you're comparing a property named `id` against a number rather than a string like is expected.